# How to differentiate between empty list and null in Sping REST URL parameter?

Tags: java, spring

I have a endpoint that accepts a list of elements. But i have 2 special cases, 1 is empty list and then is null.

Null and empty list should return different results. Null means that no filter has been applied and endpoint should return all rows from DB. But empty list means that filter exists it just has no values(there are some values in DB that if filter is empty should be returned, they have corresbonding column set to NULL).

How can i achieve this? Or do i need a new separate parameter to handle this special case?

Comment: you can use size of the list . first check is the list null -> do sth . then check if list.size() == 0 -> do sth else

Comment: But how do i pass in a empty list as a query URL param ? Right now i keep getting error 400

Comment: Differentiating between empty list and `null` brings more problems than solves. Redesign your API instead. It is also very confusing for the clients, you would have to explain them the logic and still they will use it incorrectly :)

Comment: could you set @Nullable above of the list in dto?

Comment: @mamJavad it already is nullable. Null works fine. issue is with empty list. If i try passing in empty list it just breaks.

Comment: can you send your json ?

Comment: @mamJavad got it solved. We found out that we can use NIL uuid instead. There is a special handling made for that case.

Comment: @MarkoTaht could you post your code that I can see too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate between null and empty list by making the parameter optional. Setting [RequestParam.required](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#required()) to false will do the trick.

> Switch this to false if you prefer a null value if the parameter is not present in the request.

Simplified example for testing:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<Object> test(@RequestParam(required = false) List<String> list) {
  if (list == null) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Null");
  }
  if (list.isEmpty()) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Empty");
  }
  return ResponseEntity.ok("Has Values");
}
```

Calling the url without the parameter, `/test`, will make list `null`.

Calling with parameter present, but without values - `/test?list` or `/test?list=`, will make the list empty.

Calling with values - `/test?list=11,12`, makes the list to have values.

It was mentioned in comments, but i will mention it here as well - if at all possible, redesign the API. Clients tend to forget such minute details, and it will increase the workload on the support.